# MSBuild unable to find reference for Microsoft.Win32.Registry when executing custom code snippet with dotnet core in .targets file

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

hope all is well at your end.

I wanted to find out if anyone of you have come across the following issue or figured out a way. I am getting an error when executing some custom code in my `.targets` file. I am using `net6.0-windows`.

Here is my sanitized code to simplify:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="CommonFilesDirPath" TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <CommonFilesDir ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry"/>
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Win32.Registry"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
          <![CDATA[
          CommonFilesDir = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion", "CommonFilesDir");
          Success = true;
          ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

And here is how I like to pull out the property `PropertyName` value

```
  <Target Name="FindInstallDir" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <CommonFilesDirPath>
      <Output TaskParameter="CommonFilesDir" PropertyName="CommonFilesDir" />
    </CommonFilesDirPath>
  </Target>
```

Error:

```
PS C:\git\Extension> dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
   Extension -> C:\git\Extension\src\Extension\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\Extension.dll
C:\git\Extension\src\Extension\Extension.csproj_Custom.targets(301,5): error MSB3755: Could not find reference "Microsoft.Win32.Registry". If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\git\Extension\src\Extension\Extension.csproj]
C:\git\Extension\src\Extension\Extension.csproj_Custom.targets(301,5): error MSB4175: The task factory "RoslynCodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll". The task factory must return a value for the "TaskType" property. [C:\git\Extension\src\Extension\Extension.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

Thank you,
Trushar

Comment: Could it be because there is no 6.0.0 final version of Microsoft.Win32.Registry ? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5

Comment: Yes. That’s what we are concluding for now. For now team is providing the value from project file. We shall see how this unfolds. Thank you again taking time to respond.